# Appium How to do horizontal Swipe in WebView

Tags: android, ionic-framework, appium

I'm using 5.0.2 Java-client for Appium but I'm not able to perform horizontal swipe using this:

`touchAction.press(startX, startY).moveTo(endX, startY).release().perform();`

I'm automating an Ionic application on Android.
Someone know how I can do Swipe?

Notes:
I do switch context to `WEBVIEW` to interact with the app, then I go back to `NATIVE_APP` context to use the `TouchAction`.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with 'driver.swipe', touchAction was not working for me with a web app...

Python code:

```
# Screen movement is left -> right (element is hidden at the right of the screen)
# I have a list of items (all the same) and I move 1 by 1
startX = selected.size['width']
# 'Y' coordinate in this case is the middle of the element
startY = selected.location['y'] + (selected.size['height']/2)
# This will move from startX, startY, to 1, startY in a duration of 400
driver.swipe(startX , startY, 1, startY , 400)

# Screen movement is right -> left (element is hidden at the left of the screen)
driver.swipe(1, startY, startX, startY , 400)
```

Just for the record... As I said it didnt work with touchAction for me, and for touchAction it wasnt like:

```
driver.swipe(startX , startY, 1, startY...)
```

It was like

```
touchAction.press(startX, startY).move_to((startX*-1), 0).release().perform()
```

This is for you just to consider that is acumulative... You move_to respect where you pressed...

I mean, you don't specify where coordinates do you want to move to... You specify from the origin (startX and startY), how much do you move horizontally and vertically from those coordinates...

I guess in Java will be something like this:

```
# You can change swipe duration to whatever value you want (Milliseconds)
# Screen movement is left -> right 
driver.swipe(startX, startY, 1, startY, 400);
# Screen movement is right -> left
driver.swipe(1, startY, startX, startY, 400);
```

Comment: Looks like "driver.swipe" method is deprecated in latest version of java-client for appium.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize... But anyway I made it that way... I will have to change it also

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do swipe injecting css style:

```
int width = ((Long) js.executeScript("return window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth")).intValue();
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.cssText = \"position: absolute; left: -"+ width+"px;\";", element);
```

Not sure if that is correct but worked for me.

Also, using css transform works:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.cssText = \"position: absolute; transform: translateX(-100%)\";", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues before and did the following steps to fix the issues.

1. Please make sure the start and end coordinates you select are on scrollable area of the screen.
2. Also rather than using an already existing TouchAction instance, try using a fresh one. I am yet to find an explanation as to why this worked for me.

   new TouchAction(driver).press(startX, startY).moveTo(endX, startY).release().perform();